# Countable models of first order theory of rationals

Tags: logic, reference-request, model-theory

> There is exactly one **countable** model (upto isomorphism) of the first order theory of $(\mathbb Q,<)$.

I am reading about spectrum of complete theories where the spectrum of various theories are stated (but not proved). I am looking for a reference where the above statement is proved, so that I can prove the other statements similarly, and so I can understand how can one prove such statements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The statement is proved in Theorem 2.5 [here](https://www.math.uni-hamburg.de/home/geschke/teaching/ModelTheory.pdf).

Comment: Thank you. The proof here was easier to understand than others I was finally able to find.

Answer (score 3):

But that initial claim [before it was edited] isn't true. You know from the upward Lowenheim-Skolem theorem that any theory with a countable model also has models of all larger cardinalities (which therefore won't be isomorphic with the countable model).

What *is* true is that all *countable* models of the theory of dense linear orders without endpoints look the same. It is still false that there is exactly one model: there are still many models. But at least these, the countable models, are all isomorphic.

That special result is proved in any model theory text! Or googling we find e.g. [https://www.math.ucsd.edu/~sbuss/CourseWeb/Math260_2012WS/Mar05Ricketts.pdf](https://www.math.ucsd.edu/%7Esbuss/CourseWeb/Math260_2012WS/Mar05Ricketts.pdf)

Comment: You're right, I was sloppy. I have edited my question. I couldn't find the proof of the result in most model theory texts I looked (eg: Tent and Ziegler, Hodges)

Comment: @modeltheory In Tent-Ziegler this is the first example after Theorem 2.3.4. I don't have a copy of Hodges available right now but I'd be very surprised if it's not in it

Comment: @AlessandroCodenotti You're right. The statements in the texts were actually stated in terms different to what I'm familiar to, so I was not able to find the proof until Peter's posted the link.

Comment: @modeltheory Indeed it's also in Hodges: Example 3 in Section 3.2 (p. 79 in A Shorter Model Theory). Peter Smith is not exaggerating when he writes that the result is proved in any model theory text. It is the original and canonical example of a back-and-forth argument, and the back-and-forth technique is central to model theory. I would be very surprised to find any introductory model theory book which did not contain a proof!